# How to use typescript typing for a legacy project in vscode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Currently I have a project with structure

```
...
└───folder1
│   │   file011.js
│   │   file012.js
│   └───...
└───folder2
│   │   file021.js
│   └───file022.js
│
└─── files...
```

I tried to include a `type.d.ts` to the root, then tried putting it in a typings folder but none worked.

How do I enable typing for my case ? There is no folder with name `src`

Comment: Not sure if this might help, but TypeScript 2.3 has an option to type check JS files with the `checkJS` option: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Type-Checking-JavaScript-Files

Comment: Yup that's the answer, enabling checkTs makes vscode pickup the file. Thanks :)
If you can, create an answer for it and i'll mark accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With TypeScript 2.3 you can specify the `checkJS` option to type check JS files.

Documentation: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Type-Checking-JavaScript-Files

Comment: Hi thanks, I've tried that and it works as expected. But it was in a comment from @saravanna so i'm waiting for him to create an answer to mark as accepted

Comment: ... I am Saravana? :)

Answer (score 2):

It won't work as long as your files are still named "*.js".
Try renaming a file to ".ts", then the typescript compiler can do it's magic.

You also have to create a tsconfig.json to configure the typescript compiler.

The settings really depend on the type of project you are using. If you don't use a module system like requirejs, you need to get typings for global modules.

EDIT: Removed reference to Visual Studio project settings as this question is about vscode

Comment: So you are suggesting me to change all files to `.ts` for intellisense ? It's a bit of problem as the build tool isn't that easy to pick up the change

Comment: You will only get the benefits of typescript definition intellisense inside typescript files. It sounds like, you want to use typescript definitions with your javascript. There is a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38370549/how-to-use-typescript-definitions-to-get-intellisense-for-my-own-javascript-serv