# Add custom typings file in a JavaScript VSCode project

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings, .d.ts

### Problem

I am working on JavaScript project using VSCode. I am using the `UMD` design pattern and vscode intellisense cannot recognize the exports of a module from another file. I added all the declarations in a file called `globals.d.ts`. Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to load the `globals.d.ts` declarations from my JavaScript files.

### Example Module declaration

```
export namespace ModuleName {
    export interface Item {
        toString(): string;
        property: string;
        name: string;
    }
}
```

### Example JavaScript File

```
(function (global, factory) {
    "use strict";
    if (typeof ModuleName === "undefined" && typeof require === "function") global.ModuleName = require("./mymodule.js");
    if (typeof exports !== "undefined" && typeof module !== "undefined") factory(exports);
    else factory(global.OtherModule = global.OtherModule || {});
})(this, (function (exports) {
    "use strict";

    function myMethod() {

    }

    exports.myMethod = myMethod;
    return exports;
}));
```

### What I tried

I tried using `typings install "globals.d.ts"` which created the `typings` folder, `typings.json` etc. This was only working after opening the typings file in VSCode then closing and reopening the app. That only worked while I kept the `typings` file open. This is not a very convenient way to add my interface declarations.

### About VSCode (8 months ago)

```
Version: 1.17.0
Shell: 1.7.7
Node: 7.9.0
Architecture: x64
```

### About VSCode (Now)

```
Version: 1.24.1
Shell: 1.7.12
Node: 7.9.0
Architecture: x64
```

There is no change in behavior.

Comment: typings is deprecated, you should use `npm i @types/[module]` instead

Comment: If you're dealing with local files, you shouldn't be using either. You should add these files in `includes` in your tsconfig file

Comment: If you want to reference actual type files in a JavaScript project I think you need to add a tsconfig.json file and use that to reference the custom types.  You might also be able to use `/// references` for referencing the type files.

Comment: Have you tried using JSDoc? You can paint your objects (functions) with JSDocs `@type`, `@param`, and `@returns` and intellisense will parse those.

Comment: @nickzoum, latest version of VSdcode is `Version 1.24.1 (1.24.1)`, please upgrade first and then share your feedback

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Acknowledgment

This answer was mostly copied/inspired by [Drag13's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46678663/add-custom-typings-file-in-a-javascript-vscode-project/50990886#50990886), but since it had to be modified a bit, to work with my project, I am also adding this answer.

### Solution

On top of each file where I use external code, I added:

```
if (undefined) var { -List of Namespaces used- } = require("./globals");
```

Undefined is the shortest and simplest way (that I thought of) of having a constant false value without triggering `eslint` or `jshint`. This ensures that the code will never be run, while still "requiring" the jsdoc.

I used `var` instead of `let` or `const` since it will not stay in the if scope, but rather the global file scope.

This will actually declare the variables inside the `{}` (as `undefined`), but `typeof undeclared` and `typeof undefined` are both `"undefined"`, thus there is no difference in the code.

By having all the declarations in one file, I can get all the namespaces by destructuring one require statement in one line.
But keep in mind, that in order for this to work, you need to be using `export` and not `declare` in your typings file.

### Problems with Solution

I cannot view the interfaces in `globals.d.ts` from JavaScript files.

```
export namespace Namespace {
    export interface Interface {
        property: string;
    }
}
```

I have temporarily fixed this problem by renaming the namespace with the interfaces to `Interfaces` (also fixed all the references in `globals.d.ts`) and created another Namespace with constants that implement the interfaces, like so:

```
export namespace Interfaces {
    export interface Interface {
        property: string;
    }
}

export namespace Namespace {
    export const Interface: Interfaces.Interface;
}
```

I also had trouble using the namespaces from `globals.d.ts` in JavaScript comments. To solve this problem I added `typeof` infront of the type, like so: `/** @param {typeof Namespace.Interface} */`

### Update

I have now found a way to export interfaces from `.d.ts` files to `.js` files, you can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51060207/declare-interfaces-in-typings-file-for-javascript#57322323).

Answer (score 17):

**Plain Node.JS solution**

Create next files (names should be the same):

```
lib.js 
lib.d.ts
```

Inside lib.js write some code, lets say this one:

```
function whenDo(params) {
    return params;
}

module.exports = whenDo;
```

Inside lib.d.ts write this:

```
declare function wd(params: wd.Params): wd.Params;

declare namespace wd {
    interface Params {
        name: string;
    }
}

export = wd;
```

Then, create somewhere file to consume newly created function and put this code:

```
const wd = require('./lib/lib');

const opt = wd({name:'drag13'});
console.log(opt.name);
```

And magic is here, all worked just fine.
[image]

Code was stolen from here: https://github.com/Drag13/WhenDo/blob/master/dts/index.d.ts

The approach described [here](https://drag13.io/posts/custom-typings/index.html)

Comment: I am not sure why do you need that in with typescript (cause d.ts is a typescript file) but what is the error?

Comment: Could you post your d.ts files somewhere? Because, in my solution for NodeJs interface already presented and works fine.

Comment: @nickzoum Am I correct you want to keep only one single d.ts file for all of your code?

Comment: @nickzoum That's correct, cause I can't declare types inside of the javascript (without jsdoc ofc) so I don't need interfaces directly. But in case of using jsDoc I don't how to link them. May be it is good idea to create a new question, cause we already far away from the original one.

Answer (score 8):

**ES6 import syntax solution for those who are using babel**

Create next files (names should be the same):

```
lib.js 
lib.d.ts
```

Inside lib.js write some code, lets say this one:

```
export const testMethod = (name, params) => params && params.age ? `hello ${name} with age: ${params.age}` : `hello ${name}`;
export const myConst = {
     name: 'test',
     age: 5
 };
```

Inside lib.d.ts write this:

```
declare namespace MyModule {
    interface IParams { age: number; }

    function testMethod(name: string, params: IParams): string;

    const myConst: {
        name: string,
        age: number
    }
}
export = MyModule;
```

Then, create somewhere file to consume newly created function and put this code:

```
import { testMethod } from "./lib/lib";

const name = 'drag13';
const r = testMethod(name, { age: 5 });
console.log(r);
```

Now, intellisense should works fine for params and result.

[image]

**But**. This approach requires you to use babel to friend node.js and imports. If you will try to change code from import style to require style you still will see types and arguments, but intelisence will fail.

Simple babel check:

```
npm i babel-preset-env babel-cli
./node_modules/.bin/babel-node index.js --presets env
```

*My VsCode version is 1.24.1*

Comment: You can use imports inside a node app if you use babel. But as I understand this is not possible, yeah?