# Getting Property does not exist on JSX intrinsic elements when using TSS with Javascript (no TS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm on a Javascript project (`create-react-app 2.0`), using the [tsserver](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Standalone-Server-(tsserver)) but not Typescript ([yes, it is possible](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig)), and I'm getting this linting error:

```
Property 'svg-icon' does not exist on type 'JSX.intrinsictElements'.
```

When doing something like:

```
<div>
  <svg-icons icon="student" />
</div>
```

I know from other resources it has to do with [declaring a namespace](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15449), however since my project is purely Javascript with a `jsconfig.json` file, I don't know if this solution still applies, and where would I put the file containing this namespace.

For extra context, the `svg-icon` web component is installed by one of our internal libraries and I don't handle it, but I think I don't need details from it to fix the linting here(?)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a **type declaration file (.d.ts)** for the project which provides `svg-icon`. (The .d.ts file is where you'd put the namespace.)

**If you can modify the project providing `svg-icon`**

Ideally, the .d.ts should go inside the project which provides `svg-icon`. Create a file `index.d.ts` at the root of the project which contains (at minimum):

```
declare global {
  namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
      'svg-icon': any; // you could potentially make this type more specific
    }
  }
}
```

Then reference the file by adding a `typings` field in the project's `package.json`:

```
{
  "typings": "./index.d.ts"
  ...
}
```

When you import the other project in your project, the types should (hopefully) be picked up automatically.

**If you can't modify the other project**

I couldn't find a straightforward way to do this... See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46678663/add-custom-typings-file-in-a-javascript-vscode-project) for some ideas which you might be able to adapt to your needs.

(The typical approach you'd use in a TS project is to put your custom typings inside a `typings` folder and reference the folder in `tsconfig.json` `typeRoots`, but apparently that doesn't work in JS projects.)

Comment: This creates an error: Could not install from "index.d.ts" as it does not contain a package.json file.