# Typescript: Using Declaration Merging to extend an interface for an external javascript library

Tags: typescript

I use [tinymce](https://www.tiny.cloud/) in my project and installed `@types/tinymce`. However when calling `tinymce.init()` and passing the `Settings` object some of the properties are missing in `@types/tinymce`'s `index.d.ts` and I get an error:

Calling code:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "#editor",
  height: 400,
  plugins: "paste",
  element_format: "html",
  paste_block_drop: true,
  [...]
}
```

Error message:

```
Argument of type '{ selector: string; height: number; menubar: string; toolbar: string; plugins: string; element_format: string; paste_data_images: true; paste_block_drop: boolean; paste_enable_default_filters: boolean; paste_remove_styles: boolean; paste_retain_style_properties: string; setup: (editor: Editor) => void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Settings'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'paste_block_drop' does not exist in type 'Settings'.
```

The definition in `index.d.ts` looks like this:

```
export interface Settings {
  base_url?: string;
  table_toolbar?: string;
  [...]
}
```

I searched and read several StackOverflow answers and read [Typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)  and tried to create a file `tinymce-extensions.d.ts` with this content:

```
export interface Settings {
  paste_block_drop?: boolean;
}
```

However it does not work, I still get above error message.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46678663/add-custom-typings-file-in-a-javascript-vscode-project/50990886#50990886

Comment: Make sure the d.ts file included in type definitions in your ts.config.

Comment: @Drag13 The solution cannot be to add or alter files within node_modules. Then I could alter index.d.ts directly.

Comment: @Eldar I don't think this is necessary? I extend another interface in this project and it simply works without any mods in tsconfig.json. I tried to add my d.ts file to tsconfig.json but that did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried several approaches and they are not working. I am not sure, but I have a feeling that something is broken.

So, if you can't commit this lib and still want to have types, you can use this simple, but quite ugly way:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#editor",
    height: 400,
    plugins: "paste",
    element_format: "html",
    paste_block_drop: true,
} as Settings)
```

Comment: I had to write "as tinymce.Settings" but now it works. Thanks a lot!